# Python: Access sessionStorage using requests

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, session, python-requests

I need to have access to `sessionStorage` (as with javascript) object using python requests module, is there a way to acomplish my goal; I have seen other answers and none of them seem to have adequate responses for the task I want to acomplish

If there's no way, what other alternatives do I have besides of working with selenium  (since there's a manner to do so)?

**IN SIMPLE TERMS**

I want to do this:

```
var x = sessionStorage; // js code
```

But in python 3.9 :)

Comment: `sessionStorage` is provided by the browser runtime, if your code runs outside of the browser, this object doesn't exist.

Comment: @georg So is there a manner to execute js code in runtime without the need of selenium

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: The following code was written to extract the `sessionStorage` property values from a web page into a Python `dict`.

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

# Setup.
site = 'http://www.some-site.com/page'
exp = '^[\n\s]+sessionStorage.setItem\(.*JSON.stringify\((?P<content>{.*})\)\)'

r = requests.get(site)
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = bs(r.text)
    # Extract all <script> tags from the full HTML.
    scripts = soup.findAll('script')
    # Loop through all <script> tags until sessionStorage is found.
    script = [s.string for s in scripts if 'sessionStorage' in s.decode()]
    # Use regex (with a named capture group) to extract the JSON data.
    m = re.match(exp, script[0])
    if m:
        content = m['content']
        # Convert scraped JSON data to a dict.
        data = json.loads(content)
```

**Note:** The regex pattern *may* need to be modified to suit your (a user's) specific use-case.

#### TL;DR (Background):

I ran across this question in my own search for a more elegant solution to the above code.

In my case, I was writing unit tests for a site and needed to grab the sessionStorage property from a specific web page to test that it contains the expected elements. As the data was in JSON format, this code extracts the JSON data and converts to a Python `dict` for inspection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ajax to get information from the server, you should include your `sessionStorage` data first and then attach it to the request like

```
myStorage = window.sessionStorage;
let token = myStorage.getItem('token')

$.get(url, { token: token }, function(response)() }
```

Or, if you're not using Ajax and you switch pages by refreshing your page everytime you can use cookies vs session storage which then the server can extract

```
# Python
import os, sys

sys.stderr.write("cookies:", os.getenv('HTTP_COOKIE'))
```